# Как в скрипт добавить многопоточность?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код:

```
import os

disks = []
tmp = []

def GetDisk():
    for x in ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X']:
        try:    
            path = x + ":\\"
            os.chdir(path)
            disks.append(path)
        except WindowsError:
            continue

def GetDirectory(path):
    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                if((file.split('.')[-1]) in ['pdf','doc','mov','zip','docx','rtf','png','avi','mov','jpeg','jpg','rar','raw','docm','log','mp4','img','gif']):
                    sek = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
                    tmp.append(sek)

GetDisk()
for d in disks:
    GetDirectory(d)
```

Как мне добавить многопоточность, чтобы файлы искало быстрее?

Comment: А вы ведь уже разобрались с этим вопросом? Помнится в соседнем вашем вопросе уже был многопоточный код для поиска файлов :)

Comment: Никто не отвечал просто)))

Answer (score 0):

Пример много-поточности, запускает потоки-демоны для каждого диска. Благодаря глобальной переменной может ожидать завершение работы. Можно и лучше, но как пример дял изучения сойдет.

```
import os
from ctypes import windll
from string import uppercase
from threading import Thread # библиотека много-поточности
from time import sleep

working = 0
tmp = []
ext = [
    'pdf', 'doc', 'mov', 'zip', 'docx',
    'rtf', 'png', 'avi', 'mov', 'jpeg',
    'jpg', 'rar', 'raw', 'docm', 'log',
    'mp4', 'img', 'gif'
]


def drivers():
    drives = []
    bitmask = windll.kernel32.GetLogicalDrives()

    for letter in uppercase:
        if bitmask & 1:
            drives.append(letter)

        bitmask >>= 1

    return drives


def search(disk):
    global tmp, working

    for rootdir, dirs, files in os.walk(disk + ':\\'):
        for file in files:
            if((file.split('.')[-1]) in ext):
                sek = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
                tmp.append(sek)

    working -= 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for driver in drivers():
        Thread(
            target=search,
            args=(driver,),
            daemon=True
        ).start()
        working += 1

    if working != 0:
        sleep(5)

    # Работа с дисками завершена. Все пути в tmp. Твой код дальше...
```

Comment: Ваш вариант выдал такую ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "AAAA.py", line 3, in <module>
    from string import uppercase
ImportError: cannot import name 'uppercase' from 'string' (C:\python3\lib\string
.py)

Comment: @Tayrus, тогда смените мой вариант поиска дисков обратно на свой. Не помню откуда он взялся, но раньше работал)